# Issue with typing a large text in the Espresso test script

Tags: android, android-espresso

If I try to type a large content of the text in the message body while automating it's not working. It throws the below error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get key events for string Daniel
>   is a British bloke who works with Skyscanner and LonelyPlanet on the
>   regular. He’s an amazing writer with tons of useful tips, and is an
>   even better photographer. I had the privilege of traveling with Daniel
>   and working with him in India. There was never a dull moment! His
>   photography has also been published in Beautiful Destination, Travel &
>   Leisure, National Geographic, Travel Channel and Matador Network.
>   (i.e. current IME does not understand how to translate the string into
>   key events). As a workaround, you can use replaceText action to set
>   the text directly in the EditText field.

I tried replacing the command from "typeText()" to "replaceText()" which eventually didn't work for me.

Comment: Why do you want to test an app with that long a test? If your test runs successfully for a small string, then it should work for a long string too.

Comment: Can you put the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS  - I am able to figure it out the problem. It was the problem with my Current IME only.